# What's the point of javascript templating engines?

Tags: javascript, php, underscore.js

I know the answers people typically give, but I need a concrete example as to why they are needed.

The latest impression I'm getting (mostly from underscore.js) is that it makes the code more PHP like in that you can have <% %> like ?> in PHP

The idea is to make your code less like spaghetti and have a clear difference between presentation and logic. That's what everyone says, but I'm not sure why this warrants the need for  a templating engine.

Why can't you just do this in pure javascript? All you need is a function that takes in  data as arguments and you can do keep javascript syntax without inventing a new language, which seems ridiculous. For example you can just do:

```
populateTable(obj) {
    $('#model').html('
    <h2>' + obj.title + '</h2>' +
    <ul> ... </ul>
}
```

This seems fine to me. It's a function dedicated to rendering a table using some model data that you pass into it. Why do we need to invent new syntax?

Comment: a) It's easier to write if you have larger pieces of HTML. b) You separate the presentation from the logic that populates it, which can make reusing templates easier. c) Templates are usually compiled to some intermediate representation, which should make populating the same template with different data faster. Overall, people saw a need for it and created it. If you don't see a need for it, you don't have to use it.

Comment: Not to get all nit-picky but your example has numerous syntax errors. You can't have literal newlines in strings and the strings on line 4 are not quotes.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't quite understand your point (c). How can templates--basically strings being concatenated somewhere--be compiled to anything especially in JavaScript?

Comment: What's the point of *any* templating engine? If you answer that question, you have your answer to the point of *JavaScript* templating engines.

Comment: @rvighne: Ah well, it seems they don't do as much optimization as I expected. The template is simply converted to a function, so for subsequent calls the template doesn't have to be parsed again (e.g. https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L6570). But you are right, it doesn't make a difference compared to directly using string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

One reason for me is that I prefer writing this:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Over writing this:

```
var createEntryTemplate = function(obj) {
  return '<div class="entry">' +
    '<h1>' + obj.title + '</h1>' +
    '<div class="body">' + obj.body +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
};
```

The latter method is also *more error prone* - if not for you then maybe for another person. Imagine you're working with a designer who doesn't have a lot of programming experience and he needs to go in and replace a significant chunk of HTML.

Oh crap...

Comment: +1 because you make it clear that templates just smooth over the process and don't perform magic. Good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, using a client-sided templating engine, trades server-sided rendering against client-sided execution, so these come to mind

- Pro: You might easily save significant bandwidth, as the raw data most often is much smaller than the HTML rendering
- Pro: You might easily save significant server CPU cycles by doing rendering work on the client
- Pro: The client might have more or easier accessible knowledge about the rendering restrictions (e.g. screen size)
- Con: You move the rendering from a well known and stable environment to a moving target outside your control
- Con: A non-interactive client (e.g. a search engine) will not see your final rendering, making SEO, indexing etc. hard

Comment: The OP is not even considering a server-side templating engine; they just provided that as a reference of sorts.

Comment: IIUC, the original question is "What's the point of javascript templating engines?". I tried to give my view on that.